# groovy xmlSlurper check more fields within same level

Tags: xml, groovy, double, nodes, xmlslurper

I have this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry>
    <id>E0000</id>
    <link href="href">
        <inline>
            <entry>
                <link href="href">
                    <inline>
                        <feed>
                            <entry>
                                <id>E0001</id>
                                <content type="application/xml">
                                    <props>
                                        <status/>
                                    </props>
                                </content>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <id>E0002</id>
                                <content type="application/xml">
                                    <props>
                                        <status/>
                                    </props>
                                </content>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <id>E0003</id>
                                <content type="application/xml">
                                    <props>
                                        <status>S00</status>
                                    </props>
                                </content>
                            </entry>
                        </feed>
                    </inline>
                </link>
            </entry>
        </inline>
    </link>
</entry>
```

I'm using xmlSlurper to check whether among the deepest "entry" tags, there's one having both "id" = "E0001" AND "status" = "S00" or "id" = "E0002" AND "status" = "S00".
Something like this: (id=E0001 AND status=S00) OR (id=E0002 AND status=S00).

I'm using this code (I'm testing it with Groovy Web Console).

```
    def text = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><entry><id>E0000</id><link href=\"href\"><inline><entry><link href=\"href\"><inline><feed><entry><id>E0001</id><content type=\"application/xml\"><props><status>S00</status></props></content></entry><entry><id>E0002</id><content type=\"application/xml\"><props><status/></props></content></entry><entry><id>E0003</id><content type=\"application/xml\"><props><status/></props></content></entry></feed></inline></link></entry></inline></link></entry>'
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
def result = (response.link.inline.entry.link.inline.feed.find {(it.entry.content.props.status.text() == 'S00' & it.entry.id.text().contains('E0001')) | ((it.entry.content.props.status.text() == 'S00' & it.entry.id.text().contains('E0002')))}).size() > 0 ? 'true' : 'false'
println(result)
```

But I'm getting true as result even if the status=S00 is under the "entry" tag with id=E0003 which is unwanted.
How can I tweak my above code?

Comment: Why are there `\\` before the quotes?

Comment: To test it with Groovy web console, with no \ I get a generic xml error.

Comment: You are checking all the `id`s of all childs.  Print the things you check in the `find` and you'll see for `it.entry.id.text()` `E0001E0002E0003`.  So most likely you should go deeper for the find.  Also your code uses `&` and `|`, which are binary operators - it may work or notwhile you use booleans, but it looks odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice Cfrick. I've adjusted it so and it works.

```
def result = (response.link.inline.entry.link.inline.feed.entry.find {(it.content.props.status.text() == 'S00' & it.id.text().contains('E0001')) | ((it.content.props.status.text() == 'S00' & it.id.text().contains('E0002')))}).size() > 0 ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Comment: You are still using the binary operators